# Can't install gns3,Err 502 bad gateway

Tags: networking, updates, gateway

I have Ubuntu 17.04 and I'm trying to install gns3 by using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gns3/ppa
```

Output:

```
 PPA for GNS3 and Supporting Packages. Please see http://www.gns3.com for more details
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~gns3/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpji7mkxvk/pubring.gpg' created
Error: retrieving gpg key timed out.
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gns3-gui
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.10.0-37 linux-headers-4.10.0-37-generic
  linux-image-4.10.0-37-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-37-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.10.0-37-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  augeas-lenses bridge-utils cpu-checker cpulimit dmeventd dns-root-data
  dnsmasq-base dynamips ebtables gns3-server ipxe-qemu libaio1 libaugeas0
  libboost-random1.62.0 libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libfdt1 libiscsi7
  liblvm2app2.2 liblvm2cmd2.02 libnetcf1 libqt5websockets5 librados2 librbd1
  libreadline5 libspice-server1 libvirt-bin libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon
  libvirt-daemon-system libvirt0 libvncserver1 libxen-4.8 libxenstore3.0
  libxml2-utils lvm2 msr-tools python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.qtwebsockets
  qemu-block-extra qemu-kvm qemu-system-arm qemu-system-common qemu-system-x86
  qemu-utils seabios sharutils ubridge vpcs x11vnc x11vnc-data xvfb
Suggested packages:
  augeas-doc gns3 augeas-tools numad radvd auditd systemtap nfs-common
  zfsutils pm-utils thin-provisioning-tools samba vde2 qemu-efi sgabios ovmf
  debootstrap sharutils-doc bsd-mailx | mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  augeas-lenses bridge-utils cpu-checker cpulimit dmeventd dns-root-data
  dnsmasq-base dynamips ebtables gns3-gui gns3-server ipxe-qemu libaio1
  libaugeas0 libboost-random1.62.0 libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libfdt1 libiscsi7
  liblvm2app2.2 liblvm2cmd2.02 libnetcf1 libqt5websockets5 librados2 librbd1
  libreadline5 libspice-server1 libvirt-bin libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon
  libvirt-daemon-system libvirt0 libvncserver1 libxen-4.8 libxenstore3.0
  libxml2-utils lvm2 msr-tools python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.qtwebsockets
  qemu-block-extra qemu-kvm qemu-system-arm qemu-system-common qemu-system-x86
  qemu-utils seabios sharutils ubridge vpcs x11vnc x11vnc-data xvfb
0 upgraded, 52 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 384 kB/42.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 170 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 libxenstore3.0 amd64 4.8.0-1ubuntu2.4 [19.8 kB]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libnetcf1 amd64 1:0.2.8-1ubuntu2
  502  Bad Gateway [IP: ...]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 qemu-block-extra amd64 1:2.8+dfsg-3ubuntu2.7 [38.1 kB]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 python3-pyqt5.qtwebsockets amd64 5.7+dfsg-5
  502  Bad Gateway [IP: ...]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 qemu-kvm amd64 1:2.8+dfsg-3ubuntu2.7 [13.2 kB]
Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libvncserver1 amd64 0.9.11+dfsg-1
  502  Bad Gateway [IP: ...]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 cpu-checker amd64 0.7-0ubuntu7 [6,862 B]
Ign:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 dns-root-data all 2015052300+h+1
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libreadline5 amd64 5.2+dfsg-3build1 [99.5 kB]
Err:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main i386 dns-root-data all 2015052300+h+1
  502  Bad Gateway [IP: ...]
Fetched 177 kB in 1min 10s (2,525 B/s)                                         
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/netcf/libnetcf1_0.2.8-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb  502  Bad Gateway [IP: ...]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pyqt5/python3-pyqt5.qtwebsockets_5.7+dfsg-5_amd64.deb  502  Bad Gateway [IP: ...]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libv/libvncserver/libvncserver1_0.9.11+dfsg-1_amd64.deb  502  Bad Gateway [IP: ...]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dns-root-data/dns-root-data_2015052300+h+1_all.deb  502  Bad Gateway [IP: ...]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

**Note that**: I tried to install it several times by these commands.

The last line of above output says: run `apt-get update` or try with `--fix-missing`
I updated and upgraded system several times,then i tried to install **gns3** again,But it didn't work.
And i don't know how to run `--fix-missing`.

Output of `--fix-missing`:

```
--fix-missing: command not found
```

These commands use Ubuntu-based distributions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gns3/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gns3-gui
```

When i couldn't install it that way,I decided to install it with these commands:

 Debian-based distributions:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
```

Then

Adding the following lines to your /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
```

Then running the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F88F6D313016330404F710FC9A2FD067A2E3EF7B
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gns3-gui
```

I couldn't install it again

> Error: 502 bad gateway

After these,i typed gns3 in terminal,Output:

```
The program 'gns3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install gns3
```

So i tried to install it with above command:

```
sudo apt install gns3
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dynamips libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-scripttools libqt4-svg
  libqt4-test libqtassistantclient4 libxdo3 python-qt4 python-sip xdotool
Suggested packages:
  python-qt4-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dynamips gns3 libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-scripttools libqt4-svg
  libqt4-test libqtassistantclient4 libxdo3 python-qt4 python-sip xdotool
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 438 kB/10.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 50.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libqt4-help amd64 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 [207 kB]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libqt4-svg amd64 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1
  502  Bad Gateway [IP: ...]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 python-sip amd64 4.18.1+dfsg-1 [71.8 kB]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 libxdo3 amd64 1:3.20160805.1-3
  502  Bad Gateway [IP: ...]
Fetched 279 kB in 1min 4s (4,290 B/s)                                          
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qt4-x11/libqt4-svg_4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1_amd64.deb  502  Bad Gateway [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xdotool/libxdo3_3.20160805.1-3_amd64.deb  502  Bad Gateway    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dynamips libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-scripttools libqt4-svg
  libqt4-test libqtassistantclient4 libxdo3 python-qt4 python-sip xdotool
Suggested packages:
  python-qt4-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dynamips gns3 libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-scripttools libqt4-svg
  libqt4-test libqtassistantclient4 libxdo3 python-qt4 python-sip xdotool
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 438 kB/10.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 50.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libqt4-help amd64 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1 [207 kB]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libqt4-svg amd64 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1
  502  Bad Gateway [IP: ...]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 python-sip amd64 4.18.1+dfsg-1 [71.8 kB]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 libxdo3 amd64 1:3.20160805.1-3
  502  Bad Gateway [IP: ...]
Fetched 279 kB in 1min 4s (4,290 B/s)                                          
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qt4-x11/libqt4-svg_4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1_amd64.deb  502  Bad Gateway [IP: ...]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xdotool/libxdo3_3.20160805.1-3_amd64.deb  502  Bad Gateway [IP: ...]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing? [IP:...]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Now,What should i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Install Packages ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155690/cant-install-packages-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: If this is duplicate of that question,plz tell me why can't i install gns3-gui after selecting the best server? @ChaiT.Rex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to install it...
I needed to change the server from Software Center, from US to the best server in my area
Then:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gns3/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gns3
```

Not this one:

```
sudo apt-get install gns3-gui
```

Comment: As far as I checked, the `gns3` is provided by Ubuntu repositories and is at version `0.8.7-2` which is really old. However, `gns3-gui` is provided by `ppa:gns3/ppa` repository and at the moment is at version `2.1.5`. Therefore, I do **not** recommend installing `gns3`. Instead, I recommend installing `gns3-gui` by following [these steps](https://docs.gns3.com/1QXVIihk7dsOL7Xr7Bmz4zRzTsJ02wklfImGuHwTlaA4/index.html#h.l56h7z55hmxm).