# apt-get update : Waiting for headers (Ubuntu - server 12.04)

Tags: apt, updates

While trying to execute the following command

```
    sudo apt-get-update
```

I get the following message :

```
0% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]
```

The server is directly connected to internet and there is no proxy between. I am able to ping the ubuntu update servers and also use wget to download the files from the Ubuntu update servers.

I have also tried the solutions from the answer of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94831/stuck-at-0-waiting-for-headers-apt), with no luck

Please help me to resolve this issue.

---

Dear Friends,

If you are marking my question as duplicate, please give the link of the solution. Or at least the steps required to analyse this issue.

Thank You

With Regards

Santhanam

Comment: @StephenMyall : Before posting in this forum itself, i have tried the solutions mentioned in your link. Still there is no resolution of the issue. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Look at the top of your question: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VI7qE.png

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question will be closed as a duplicate. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!