# How do I resolve webpage encoding issues when using a proxy?

Tags: networking

Unless I disable proxy, webpages show up as characters like

```
|ˆSš˜mð{ýîsqÐ|0MVà|ð|}}}0}@}P}`}p}€}P} }°}À}Ð}à}ð}~~ ~0~@~P~`~p~€~P~ ~°~À~Ð~à~€€ €0€@€P€`€p€€€P€ €°€À€Ð€à€ð€AA A0A@APA`ApA€APA A°AÀAÐAàAðA‚‚
```

or else as a `.bin` file available for download. For example https://dpaste.de/epVx is what http://stumblingandmumbling.typepad.com/stumbling_and_mumbling/2014/03/ex-growth.html looks like if I go through the system proxy.

---

If I use `w3m` through an `ssh` connection then webpages display fine. `TTYtter` works fine. `vlc` can even play the same youtube video at the same time as firefox can't load the site. I infer from this that those programs must use proxies differently.

Once I change the proxy from "system default" to "none" this problem goes away in Firefox. Aliasing `w3m` to `w3m -no-proxy` works for naked `w3m` but not in wrappers like `surfraw`. However, `curl` and by extension `R` still can't fetch data—and even `sudo apt-get install` is having problems.

I'm not even sure where the system default proxy settings are coming from. If I try to google about it I end up being directed to `squid` -- which I'm not sure is what I want.

Comment: Which browsers you use that this happens? Also, don't you have a proxy in your network? How you disable the proxy?

Comment: There is no default web proxy server for Ubuntu, at least not on normal installations.  On a network you might be forced to use a proxy, though.  Have you checked your Firefox configurations and configs on your other browsers to see whether they're even being assigned a proxy?

Comment: @Braiam Firefox and `w3m` both had the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had installed `anon-proxy` but not configured it. `anon-proxy` uses `127.0.0.1:4001`. So either configure it or kill it.

- [How to configure anon-proxy.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=873544&p=5664314#post5664314)
- To kill it use `sudo su; netstat -tlp` to find the process number of `mix` (it's called an anonymous mix for some reason) and then from `su` issue `kill -9` to the process id number.
- If killing doesn't work, then don't just `sudo apt-get remove anon-proxy`; also `sudo apt-get purge anon-proxy`; this will unset shell variables like `$HTTP_PROXY` and some files in `/etc/` or `/var/` that it may have changed.