# Why is Apt stopping at "0% [Waiting for headers]" on this network and how can it be addressed?

Tags: wireless, apt

I'm at a conference and using the local Wi-Fi network. The internet connection is working, but any attempt at installing packages using Apt results in the installation halting at `0% [Waiting for headers]`. On a different Wi-Fi network, the installation proceeds successfully (the hotel Wi-Fi). Why might it be stopping? Assuming I have no control over the Wi-Fi network, how can this be addressed?

Comment: It depends on that specific network settings and can be addressed by IT department only.

Comment: Check out this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/94831/stuck-at-0-waiting-for-headers?rq=1 and this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/156650/apt-get-update-very-slow-stuck-at-waiting-for-headers?rq=1

Comment: Can you `ping` your Apt mirror and establish a connection to it in a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, that represents a network issues on the Wifi. Maybe the router have sort of ACL list.

You can check for the connectivity by running `mtr` tool, and ping actual repos. F.E:

```
apt-get install mtr
mtr ppa.launchpad.net
```

And see where it get's blocked, is it dropping a connection somewhere.. Also, wireshark/tcpdump are good for resolving as well.

Comment: That would be interesting but if the user can't install updates, he can't install other software (from the repos) either. Installing everything while using other network should work though.