# Can't install wxmaxima on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: software-installation

When trying to install the wxmaxima app from the Ubuntu Software Center I am getting this error:

`Failed to fetch http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gmp4/libgmp3c2_4.3.2+dfsg-2ubuntu1_i386.deb 403  Forbidden`

I suppose that for some reason the file isn't availabe in the .pt server. Is there anyway to try with a different one?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a different server. The Spanish mirror (es.archive.ubuntu.com) has it.

Comment: how can I do that?