# Problem with Ubuntu Software Center download rate

Tags: 11.10, software-center, download-speed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me)

When I download something from the Ubuntu Software Center, it usually downloads at about a 40kb/s speed. Thing is, I can download things from the internet at 1MB/s+ and sometimes as high as 2.2MB/s. Why is it so slow? Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

Try a different mirror.

There is a list here : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors

Select a mirror close to you with a large bandwidth.

Synaptic also has the ability to identify the fastest mirror.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-select-fastest-mirror-in-ubuntu.html

You will have to install synaptic first of course =)