# "Testing Download Servers" hangs

Tags: 11.10, package-management, repository, software-sources

From **Software Sources | Select Best Server**, the "**Testing Download Servers**" progress bar only gets halfway through and then hangs.  Tried several times over many different days, and predictably hangs at the same spot.

Downloading from the repositories is painfully slow, like 30Kbs, so would very much like to find a faster server.  Any suggestions to either get past this problem or perhaps suggest fast servers that keep current with releases?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know about the cause of your problem, but a work around might be to manually select a mirror

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Choose one near your with a large bandwidth. Sounds as if almost any mirror will work.

- [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me)

Comment: Shweeeet!  Bandwidth and Update Currency provided.  PERFECT!  Thanks BODHI.ZAZEN!  Be zen amigo.  :-)