# Trouble installing package and updating

Tags: updates, package-management

I almost nothing about Ubuntu. When I try to run the command to install of a package, I am said that 'unable to locate package'

When I try to run sudo apt-get update, the system seems being blocked! Here's what I get:

[image]

Does anybody has an idea ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/111597/how-can-i-work-around-something-wicked-happened-resolving-mirror-errors