# Error during updating ubuntu 12.10

Tags: updates

I installed ubuntu 12.10 using windows installer(wubi). When I tried to update it using "sudo apt-get update", it didn't work and showed something like this

Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages

I'm using a proxy network.I'm a beginner.So, plz tell me what to do in detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/111597/

Answer (score 0):

It cannot resolve hostname. You may need to change the nameserver to 8.8.8.8

Comment: I recommend expanding this answer to explain how to do that.

Comment: I've already done that(change the nameserver), didn't work.