# Why I do get error 101? How is my DNS involved?

Tags: apt

I was getting `Update information is outdated` alert. I tried `sudo apt-get update` and got these errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'repository.spotify.com:http' (-11 - System error)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/i18n/Translation-en  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/source/Sources  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/source/Sources  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/source/Sources  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/source/Sources  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111597/how-can-i-work-around-something-wicked-happened-resolving-mirror-errors) thread's top answer and it fixed the problem.

But someone please explain what was the problem and how did it got fixed?

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting those kind of errors it means that either, your IPv6 connection was unstable, or the servers were dead, or the file was not found. Right now is working through:

```
http://[2001:67c:1562::13]/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/binary-i386/
```

Answer (score 3):

What you can see in the output is that your machine is trying to connect using IPV6 addresses (e.g. 2001:67c:1562::13 )  which are distinguishable from IPv4 addresses (e.g 192.168.0.1).  You could have two approaches here. One - disable IPv6 following [these](https://askubuntu.com/a/309463/295286) steps:

1. Open your `/etc/sysctl.conf` with any text editor ( you'll need `sudo` for that ). I personally would do something like `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf` ( `nano` is easiest ) or `sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf`.
2. add these lines:

   ```
    net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
    net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
    net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
   ```
3. Run `sudo sysctl --load` to apply changes.

The second way would be to temporarily use ipv4 to update instead of ipv6 only for one time.

```
sudo apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update
```

The third way would be to use IPv6 DNS. For instance, click on network indicator in top panel, select `Edit Connections`, and for your specific wifi or ethernet connection, use `2620:0:ccc::2` dns, which [OpenDNS IPv6 server](https://www.opendns.com/about/innovations/ipv6/). Make sure you select "Address only" option

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your network proxy settings in sync with the one you are using to access this web-page (in short your browser's proxy)

Comment: The question is “why?” not “how do I fix this?”. I also find it pretty far fetched to assume a proxy configuration error when the logs just show rather generic IP networking errors. Lastly it would be better to describe in detail how to perform the mentioned changes (see [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer)).