# $sudo apt-get update throws (101: Network is unreachable)

Tags: 14.04, update-manager

```
insane@ubuntu:~/Auto$ sudo apt-get update
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
  Cannot initiate the connection to extras.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease

Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::18 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to extras.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::18 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

    enter code here
```

Comment: well - do you have internet? which version of ubuntu do you use? which mirror servers are configured?

Comment: I am on ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-i386.iso and active internet connection
I am performing $sudo apt-get update after updating the proxy settings from System Settings>> Network>> Manual Proxy

Comment: check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/334886/why-i-do-get-error-101-how-is-my-dns-involved

Comment: I voted to close it as it confirmed to be a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1412943