# sudo apt-get update fails on postgresql

Tags: apt, updates, postgresql, nodejs

I am trying to install nodejs but it keeps on failing. So I have uninstalled nodejs and found out that sudo apt-get update still fails. It's been so long that I have used postgresql. but here is my error during sudo apt-get update:

```
  Get:41 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Translation-en [81.6 kB]                                                        
Err http://apt.postgresql.org precise-pgdg InRelease                                                                                       

Err http://apt.postgresql.org precise-pgdg Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to apt.postgresql.org:80 (2a00:f10:111:50::228). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a00:f10:111:50::228 80]
Fetched 14.4 MB in 6min 3s (39.5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/precise-pgdg/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/precise-pgdg/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to apt.postgresql.org:80 (2a00:f10:111:50::228). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a00:f10:111:50::228 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

As you can see, the first line succeeded and the rest of updates above it. The error started on the second line. I do not know where else to go. Please help me. I could not proceed with anything since sudo apt-get update has a problem.

Comment: Can you connect in a web browser to http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/precise-pgdg/InRelease ?

Comment: Yes i can connect to that url using my browser chrome. It shows SHA256. 
But on terminal, using sudo apt-get update, it cannot connect.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list) and [Why I do get error 101? How is my DNS involved?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/334886/why-i-do-get-error-101-how-is-my-dns-involved)

Answer (score -1):

**What caused the problem**

Checking out ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/, vivid is not a child directory, meaning it is not supported.  This is because ubuntu 15.04 vivid vervet is at it's end of life (see wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_life).

**Solution 1: Upgrade your Ubuntu OS to 16.04.**
This version should be stable for a long time (~2021), and so is likely to remain supported by Node for a similar duration.  Then you'd have to update the ppa you're using and `sudo apt-get update`.

Still, that's a lot of work. You could try

**Solution 2: install from source or debian packages.**
The instructions on [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) seem pretty comprehensive. I want to say installing from  debian packages from nodesource worked for me on ubuntu 15.04, but honestly I might have used

**Solution 3: use nvm to upgrade.** Instructions can be found [here](https://davidwalsh.name/nvm).

Comment: No the problem was caused by a network error on `apt.postgresql.org`. All the other messages are warnings. -1