# Issues with Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop Repo

Tags: 20.04, update-manager, repository

Today I'm experiencing problems with Ubuntu Repo:

```
raphy@pc:~$ sudo apt-get update 
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                
Ign:3 https://download.arangodb.com/arangodb39/DEBIAN  InRelease                                                                                                             
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                 
Hit:5 https://download.arangodb.com/arangodb39/DEBIAN  Release                                      
Hit:7 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                          
Err:8 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease             
  Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:72). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (90.147.160.72), connection timed out Could not connect to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (90.147.160.73), connection timed out Could not connect to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (90.147.160.70), connection timed out
Err:9 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease     
  Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:72). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:10 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:72). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:72). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (90.147.160.72), connection timed out Could not connect to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (90.147.160.73), connection timed out Could not connect to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (90.147.160.70), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:72). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:70). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:73). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to it.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:760:ffff:b6:4:100:0:72). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
raphy@pc:~$
```

What do I have to do solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to fetch security undetermined error \[IP: 91.189.91.38 80\] in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305141/failed-to-fetch-security-undetermined-error-ip-91-189-91-38-80-in-ubuntu-20-0)

Comment: Thank you @Raffa !!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I do get error 101? How is my DNS involved?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334886/why-i-do-get-error-101-how-is-my-dns-involved)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message indicates, the server it.archive.ubuntu.com does not respond. Wait and try later, or temporarily switch to another software server ("Software & Updates", "Ubuntu Software" tab).

Comment: Thank you @vanadium