# "sudo apt-get update" fails

Tags: networking, updates, openvpn

New to Ubuntu/Linux.  Having issues updating an Ubuntu OpenVPN VM.  When I entered the command, it comes back with "Failed to fetch http:...... Cannot initiate the connection to ..... (101: Network is unreachable)"
Ran PING test (both name and IP) to the various sites on the update list, and got replies from all.
I don't believe there is an issue on my network because I have other Ubuntu VMs and all of them able to run sudo update & upgrade without issues.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please help us help you and expand on "Failed to fetch http:......" turns out ...... is meaningless. Thanks

Comment: Failed to fetch http is followed by all the websites the update process is trying to reach, there are many sites, and it fails to connect to any of them.  Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I do get error 101? How is my DNS involved?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/334886/why-i-do-get-error-101-how-is-my-dns-involved)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/111597/how-can-i-work-around-something-wicked-happened-resolving-mirror-errors

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful suggestions, however, none fixed the issues. I disabled ipv6 and updated the DNS.  I'm still getting multiple lines of unable to reach sites.  Below is an example
"Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]"

I don't have any issues ping to those sites or the IPs.