# software for ubuntu

Tags: installation, package-management

I M new user for Ubuntu 11.10...In Ubuntu 11.10 take much time for specified software via software center. for example I download wine for window uploader using usb data card @2g speed. its take nearly 3 hours for installation. But in winxp u can download .exe file with download manager very fast (100 MB in 40 min. with BSNL SIM) and installed it any time. Now I want to know how to download fast in Ubuntu 11.10
MY requirement is under please.

1. FDM for video download via youtube.com using browser
2. Audio/Video Codec for verious format like FLV, 3gp avi,
3. HindiIndic(IME)/English option for office work (in MS Office I can change typing language   by pressing alt+shift key)
4. Nero

Comment: You may get a better download speed on choosing another mirror (see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/37825/3940)).

Answer (score 2):

sometimes a software you want to download needs to download extra libraries, not only it's binary to be run,
but the good news is that when the library is downloaded, it 'might' be used by another application, so in future you (again might) need to download less

for the issue of "being able to install anytime", it's possible,
copy the archives at this path somewhere: /var/cache/apt/archives/
you don't the folder partial, and the file 'lock', don't change permissions of lock or delete it 
next time you want to install wine(let's say after a fresh installation) just copy back the archives to the path mentioned, *but* you have to update repository list before by

```
sudo apt-get update
```

you can even give the archives to your friend and all he same as you has to copy archives to path and update repositories, and install,

for codecs install packages "gstreamer" in software center, not all of them will show up, you should choose show "technical stuff" (maybe it had another name, but something like this)

 nero is not free,  instructions of downloading will be given after purchasing from ahead company,  but there many many free similar softwares, before spending money i suggest you to try them, if you have an image in nrg format use software nrg2iso to convert them
i dont know what fdm is, but for languages you just have to add them in settings/keyboard layouts/layouts, add it there, 
if the key sequence alt+shift doesn'y work set it by clicking the "option" key, located it the same window you add languages

 good luck!

Comment: Thanks 4 ur reply... (FDM) Free download Manager is powerful, easy-to-use and absolutely free download accelerator and manager in window XP...

Comment: hmmm, you know, i use Flashget through wine occasionally, i don't bother to find a better one than flashget, i use 'axel' and 'wget' try them they are very simple that's what i like about it, but to GUI, though you can easily find one for wget