# Rhythmbox and dependencies not getting installed or upgraded in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox

After `apt-get update --fix-missing` when I do `apt-get upgrade` I get this:

The following packages have been kept back:

```
linux-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae linux-image-generic-pae unity-scope-musicstores usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

On `apt-get dist-upgrade`, the result is:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:

linux-headers-3.2.0-24 linux-headers-3.2.0-24-generic-pae linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic-pae rhythmbox rhythmbox-data
  rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins rhythmbox-ubuntuone syslinux-legacy

The following packages will be upgraded:

  linux-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae linux-image-generic-pae unity-scope-musicstores usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk

6 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Need to get 395 kB/51.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 186 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y

Err "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder i386 2.96-0ubuntu4
  403  Forbidden

Err "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist all 2.96-0ubuntu4
  403  Forbidden

Err "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main rhythmbox-plugins i386 2.96-0ubuntu4
  403  Forbidden

Failed to fetch "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/rhythmbox/rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder_2.96-0ubuntu4_i386.deb  
403  Forbidden

Failed to fetch "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/rhythmbox/rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist_2.96-0ubuntu4_all.deb  
403  Forbidden

Failed to fetch "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/rhythmbox/rhythmbox-plugins_2.96-0ubuntu4_i386.deb  
403  Forbidden

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

`apt-get update --fix-missing` isn't resolving the problem. How can I solve this?

Note: I have prefixed the hyperlinks with " as i couldn't post question with >2 links

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a problem with your local mirror being out of date, try this:

- [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)