# 'sudo apt-get update' error on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt

When I type in `sudo apt-get update` I get this:

```
mohd-arafat-hossain@TUD:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for mohd-arafat-hossain:
Ign http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Ign http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease                     
Ign http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease                   
Ign http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                           
Ign http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg                   
Ign http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg                 
Ign http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                               
Ign http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                       
Ign http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                     
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex           
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex           
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                    
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release                        
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex   
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex   
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en             
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex   
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                   
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en             
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en           
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex      
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en     
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en         
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources     
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How do solve this issue and not get this error.? Please

Comment: Whether it happened only once or every time u run the command? Are u sure the Internet connection is not get reconnected in the meanwhile?

Comment: Thanks.! I altered the source in the software center -- changed the download from "main server" to "Server from united states" Then i did a sudo apt-get update problem solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something I always try to do whenever I am updating Ubuntu 12.04 packages is make sure I will be downloading them from the closest/best mirror/server.

1. Begin by launching the software center.
2. Select edit from the menu bar, then select Software Sources. ..

[image: Software Center Edit Menu]

3. Click the drop down arrow for the Download From options.

[image: Package Sources download options]

4. Choose other.

[image: other download server]

5. Click "Select Best Server."

[image: Selecting Best download server ubuntu 12.04]

6. Software center will now perform a series of tests to find the best mirror for your location.

[image: Finding Closest Server]

Source: http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/sudo-apt-get-update-error-slow-mirror-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: Software Center then says "To change software repository settings, you need to authenticate... Authentication as the super user is required" and asks for "Password for temp" (not my username). How do I authenticate?

Answer (score 7):

Looking on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirrors.ispros.com.bd-archive, it seems that the Bangladesh mirror has not been updated with Precise packages yet. You may want to [select a different nearby mirror](https://askubuntu.com/q/37753/6969) (India comes to my mind) or file a bug about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude IT WORKED!!!!
I changed to an India mirror and the update completed successfully...I used this method >>> http://askubuntu.com/a/37825/58164
Thanks Again :)

Comment: "Thanks a lot dude IT WORKED!!!" :D That's one to remember...

Comment: I had to change from India to main server

Answer (score 1):

The error you have got is because the link has actually been removed. This might be temporary or the server might not be working properly or under maintenance.(in your case the package files have not been uploaded on the server)
To solve this you try changing your download source(this may or may not work depending on the server)
open `software sources`
click on `ubuntu software` tab
then in `Download from` choose other and then click on `select best server`
After that software sources will automatically be updated.