# Apt-get update fails ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, updates

I im trying to do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

but i get the following error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.udc.es/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find   expected entry 'main/binary-x8-64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

I have tried resetting the /etc/apt/sources.list like is here suggested:

[How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

And also tried to select another server from which to download the updates: ['sudo apt-get update' error on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128369/sudo-apt-get-update-error-on-ubuntu-12-04?lq=1)

But I keep getting the same damned error message. Any ideas?

As asked in comment, doing:

```
$ grep -R ftp.udc.es /etc/apt/sources.list*
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ftp.udc.es/ubuntu/ trusty main universe
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://ftp.udc.es/ubuntu/ trusty main

$ cat sources.list
## See sources.list(5) for more information, especialy
# Remember that you can only use http, ftp or file URIs
deb http://ftp.udc.es/ubuntu/ trusty main universe
# CDROMs are managed through the apt-cdrom tool.

$ dpkg --print-architecture 
amd64
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386 
x8664
x8-64
x864
```

Comment: It doesnt return anything...

Comment: Odd. I think the error is actually because `x8-64` isn't a valid architecture option for Debian repositories, yet your sources seem to use it. What about `grep -R ftp.udc.es /etc/apt/sources.list*`?

Comment: pastebin the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` so we can check the syntax.

Comment: I put both things in the question since its not too big

Comment: And `dpkg --print-architecture; dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` as well, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Comment: How can it be malformed if I have reseted it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As can be seen from the output of `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`, you have a bunch of invalid architectures added, for some reason. Remove them:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture x8664
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture x8-64
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture x864
```

In future, do check what you're adding.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` . These are the us repositories.

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

---

you might get the error because Canonical has deprecated 14.04 ( before being blessed LTS) . If you are not on LTS then you should upgrade to 14.04.01 LTS.

You do that by running `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: Im at 14.04.01, sorry. i did the command that you suggested anyway and got:
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found

Comment: Can you try this on plain command line: `curl http://ftp.udc.es/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release`

Comment: I did it but update keeps failing

Comment: I'm asking if curl says 404 page not found? I'm trying to see if your IP is not blocked. The repo is accessible from this side of the world.

Comment: No it doesnt, it returns the MD5 sum, a number and the name

Comment: Doing that gives more errors (I cant put all of them, but they are all alike):  
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'deb-src/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Comment: I've added a copy of the us repositories you can add to sources. After you add them, run `sudo apt-get updated` and then retry to install.

Comment: Could you check for typos in your file? I've pasted a copy of my working `/etc/apt/sources.list` .

Comment: I commented my file (the one line in it, and used yours, and still get lots of errors, (like the one in the last comment)

Comment: sorry, can't think of anything else. I'd dare say try `do-release-upgrade -d`, but that **WILL UPGRADE** to the current **DEVELOPMENT** version.

Comment: After a lot of researches, I tried both (adding the repos and upgrade). This fixed my problem! Thanks to share this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Software and Update*, and in *Ubuntu Software* tab, change the download location to *Select best server*. It  will update the cache and after that, youer done. Then try `apt-get update`.