# Failed to fetch .... i386 - 404 Not Found - Jetson TK1 board

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

So I am having a lot of difficulties with getting my TK1 board setup and ready for development.

I tried installing Chrome and I got an error related to "i386" when I tried to install it.
I also tried installing Teamviewer and I also got the same error.

Now, whenever I try to run "sudo apt-get update" or anyhting similar, I get errors related to not able to get i386 package:

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:/var/lib/apt/lists$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/main armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001:1::2 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001:1::2 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001:1::2 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001:1::2 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001:1::2 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001:1::2 80]
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001:1::2 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001:1::2 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001:1::2 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001:1::2 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001:1::2 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001:1::2 80]
```

This is what is in my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates main restricted

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'universe'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty universe
# deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-backports main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-backports main restricted

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security main restricted
# deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security universe
# deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security multiverse
```

I tried cleaning stuff using "sudo apt-get clean" and "sudo apt-get autoclean", etc.. but to no good. I am not sure why after downloading and trying to install **chrome** or **teamviewer**, I would get this error.

I would appreciate any help with this...

Comment: It's not technically a duplicate though. It just happened that the answer in that question solved my problem. Mine is strictly related to i386 while the given answer is related to another type of architecture and with a different error message. I still believe this question will be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

So after a good night of sleep, I decided to google the issue with a failed "sudo apt-get update" and I found that the following thing fixed my issue:

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

Apparently, I had added a foreign architecture "i386" and that was causing all the issues and I am not sure why I didn't see this before.

There you go, I hope this helps someone else.

**This is the link that helped me try this approach. It's not exactly the same issue, but the solution is the same:** [Apt-get update fails ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590244/apt-get-update-fails-ubuntu-14-04)