# Slow apt-get update in 12.04 new instalation

Tags: apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

I take long to make apt-get update, is it a momentary situation that servers are saturated or is a permanent situation?

Answer (score 3):

To improve the speed of the update I let the software center choose the best server for my connection at the time.

Try:

- open the software center and going Edit -> Software sources...
- In the 'Download from' dropdown choose Other...
- Click 'Select Best Server' button

Answer (score 0):

At the first running of apt-get update it usually takes more time as it downloads the language support. In next updates it should run normally.