# How do which sites I have selected affect updates?

Tags: apt, updates, software-center

Does it matter what site you choose for updates?

Do you get the same updates no matter what site you choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you refer to the repositories when you refer to 'site'
(The thing you select from 'software sources')

The differences may be:

- Speed. Mirrors close to your physical location usually serve updates at slightly greater speed.
- Time: At times, there is a delay between synchronizations, so you may get updates a little later, depending on the mirror you choose.

That said, All repositories are periodically synchronized to have **Exactly the same content.** So It really doesn't matter what repo you choose.

As a side note, [This QA thread has information on how to choose a mirror to maximise download speed.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)