# download updates extremely slow

Tags: apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

i've looked through the forum havent really found anything recent that pertains so i figured i would ask, im on a 25mbit connection i download around 2.2MB/s however my download speeds for download updates and software in ubuntu 12.04 is extremely slow, i went into the software center and changed to US as im in Illinois USA and my download speed is still excruciating went from about 700B/s to 9000B/s is anyone aware of what is going on here? are the servers REALLY that slow? took me like 4 minutes to download the whole Ubuntu installation this is ridiculous

PC: Quad core 3.0GHZ AMD
GT 440 1GB video card
12GB ram
2TB HDD

Comment: i should add that when i say it took me 4 minutes to download the whole OS i cant believe the updates are this slow lol HELP ME PLZ :D

Comment: umm.. stupid but i went into Ubuntu Software center > Edit > software sources > other choose other then test sources lol.. done deal

Comment: Are you saying that solved your problem?

Comment: Duplicate of [http://askubuntu.com/q/37753/52923](http://askubuntu.com/q/37753/52923).