# Apt commands take a lot of time initially

Tags: networking, apt

I am using kubuntu 16.04.
I have quite a good internet connection, max upto 50Mbps.
But for some reason the apt commands take a lot of time initially.

As soon as you execute the apt-get update, you get a percentage progress.
Mine gets stuck for upto 15-20 seconds in the [0% working] stage.
Once it starts, then it is quite fast.

I looked at this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/749733/435637
and tried his solution, but it did not work for me.

How do i understand or find out the cause of this problem?