# Installation hangs at "Retrieving file 43 of 105"

Tags: upgrade

This is my second attempt at installing Ubuntu. In my first attempt, I selected "download updates" and "install third-party components"; in my second attempt, I deselected both. Still experiencing the same problem.

In my first attempt at installing Ubuntu, after the installation stuck at "Retrieving file 43 of 105", I selected "skip" and the installation completed. After I started to run the OS, I received a notification that language support was incomplete. When I tried to update it, the Ubuntu Software Centre updating process hung on "waiting for jockey-backend to exit", seemingly indefinitely.

At that point, I decided to reinstall the system (since the whole process is only supposed to take 45 minutes or less), but, as I mentioned above my results were the same.

I'm new to Ubuntu. Any advice? Where are the files (including file 43) being retrieved from? Online or from the ubuntu installation iso?

I have searched many forums for an answer to this problem, and have seen others with the same issue but I haven't found a solution.

Comment: I just [killed the jockey-backend process](http://naveenubuntu.blogspot.ca/2011/09/waiting-for-jockey-backend-to-exit.html), even though I don't believe all my drivers are enabled. Now, the Ubuntu Software Centre processes window is stuck on "Updating Cache: Querying software sources". The Update Manager is still "waiting" and has not begun the process of installing the 53 updates.

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck on retrieving file 43 of 105 as well, to get past it I simply turned off the wifi button on my laptop and cut off the internet, it then stopped downloading and proceeded with the installation :)

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if your internet connection disconnects or the mirror you are connected to times out or something. It's just installing the normal software updates during installation to save you the trouble of doing it after installation.

You can ignore the problem during installation, and then try again after your system is up and running. If you're consistently having connections problems with your update mirror consider selecting a new one:

- [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

Answer (score 1):

Like Emmanuel said, disconnecting from all networks is probably the best solution to get a clean install.  I do lots of installations at my school where we are behind a proxy; downloading updates while installing always leads to issues, and sometimes the installation errors out without downloading update selected simply because the computer is connected via Ethernet.

So, when installing, you have two options to prevent network activity:

1. Unplug the Ethernet cable from your computer (wired network), and don't connect to a wireless network; this is my suggestion
2. When Ubuntu loads and asks you to try or install, click the network notification icon, and click to uncheck "Enable Networking"

After you get a successful installation, use the terminal to update, so you can see more clearly where the update is failing.  Open a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T and type this and press the enter key:

`sudo apt-get update`

If this does not return any errors, proceed by typing this and pressing enter:

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`