# When I install Ubuntu it takes long in the preparing to download, what can I do?

Tags: system-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu, and it takes a long time in the preparing to install the screen, and I don't know what to do, please help? The reason I'm installing it is because my computer fails to start to windows 7 and the only way I can use it is with Ubuntu, so now I'm stuck with using it on the try Ubuntu. I need to install it, but it takes long as I said before I press continue and it takes a long time to go to the next part so I don't know what to do. what can I do? I'm using Ubuntu (try) right now.

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/q/156535/169736

Answer (score 1):

Normally, whenever you download updates it takes a **very looong time**. Because you are downloading several megabytes of updates (some of them seems stuck, but it's doing it work). If you don't have a fast internet, either **wait** or don't use *Update at install* option. Is reported that if you unplug/disconnect every network the installation will continue without problems.