# Unable to install Security update in ubuntu

Tags: updates, update-manager

Are these security updates necessary for my computer?
My system is able to download all other security update but these update it fails to download.

How can I install it?

[image]

After using `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` 
Then also it failed to update

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those are kernel and kernel header updates which are major security updates for your system. Thus they are necessary in the security aspect. You can install them by command in terminal:

Open terminal by the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and enter these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And then reboot the system to have them taken effect.

Answer (score 0):

you have kernel headers there so you should run

`sudo apt-get update`

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

from the man apt-get

```
 dist-upgrade
   dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
   also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
   of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
   it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
   expense of less important ones if necessary. So, dist-upgrade
   command may remove some packages. The /etc/apt/sources.list file
   contains a list of locations from which to retrieve desired package
   files. See also apt_preferences(5) for a mechanism for overriding
   the general settings for individual packages
```

if you are notify you should remove some older dependencies run

```
sudo apt-get autoclear && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and here you have a complete 
[apt-get guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)

Comment: still i m unable to download the update package.u can see the new result, i hav uploaded a new image

Comment: its the complete output ?? it says its a connection problem !!

Comment: some one  open other question about restricted connection to those servers , check if this is your case on some restriction http://askubuntu.com/questions/159073/how-can-i-update-ubuntu-if-the-update-servers-are-blocked?rq=1

Comment: I m able to update all package except the package show in the 1st image which i uploded. I also changed my update download server from india to main server but still same problem resides.It is unable to download Linux.image 3.19.039 generic package...

Comment: yeah but all the photo show is a connection error ..., thats whay im asking you if that is the complete output from the error . try to read and post the output from  ` cat /var/log/apt/term.log | grep error`
´

Comment: Output after using command cat /var/log/apt/term.log | grep error  [link](http://s20.postimg.org/gikbrohv1/lll.png) .One information i want to add that it is always showing connection problem but i must guarantee u that there is no such issue.I just updated my google chrome with no such issue but when i try to update linux-image-extra-3.19.0-39-generic it shows connection problem.

Comment: ok , your new picture is telling you you have some dependencies missing , and you should try to run the command with the --fix-missing attribute  , becouse the output is telling you to try with that .

Comment: tried all command like autoremove, --fix missing but none of them worked .u can see the output  [link](http://s20.postimg.org/w9ax1sodp/lpo.png)

Comment: mmm...in the pic you post , you try to run apt-get dist-upgrade -f (--fix-missing) // not install --fix-missing .

Comment: Which command r u telling me to use?

Comment: output after using apt-get install --fix-missing   [link](http://s20.postimg.org/d5hllgbjh/lpk.png)

Comment: mi friend you have to use  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade --fix-missing

Comment: Only these two package named "linux image 3.19.0-genric & linux kernel extra module for versio 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86" U see the output what happen wen i try to update it..[link](http://s20.postimg.org/asdwj1i7h/lopk.png)