# ubuntu 12.04 archive.ubuntu.com fails to connect during update

Tags: 12.04, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

I have Ubuntu 12.04 unity and when I try to do a `sudo apt-get update` it fails to connect to `archive.ubuntu.com` which also fail to connect via browser, her's what I get in terminal:

```
moqane@home:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for moqane: 
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release     
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources                   
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US 
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease
88% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com]
```

I think that something's wrong and the website is only down for me, if you have any ideas feel free to help...

Thank you.

Comment: Try changing your Mirror from `software sources`

Comment: This is happening to me too. And no one seems to know a fix.

Comment: @tijybba Hi, I did that with Update manager with no luck

Comment: Have you checked your Internet connection?

Comment: @Mitch My connection is fine I guess as I can browse the Internet fine

Comment: What server do you have listed in the Software Sources window?

Comment: does the website "archive.ubuntu.com" is down for you guys or just me?

Comment: @Mitch I is the "Main Server".

Comment: No main server is NOT down , i just checked it, it works.

Answer (score 2):

There is a 7 step Package Manager Troubleshooting Procedure available at [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure)  Have a look at it, and let me know if it works.