# Download issue with software center

Tags: software-center, downloads

OK so i just got xfinity setup at my house and i seem to be having trouble downloading from the software center. all it comes up with is this:

```
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/libwbclient0_3.5.11~dfsg-1ubuntu2.2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]

Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/smbclient_3.5.11~dfsg-1ubuntu2.2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
```

can you help?

Comment: Those files do not exist. I suggest you try again later, since the said packages are probably still in the process of being uploaded.

Answer (score 3):

Okay try this:

Open up the Ubuntu Software Center and click on Edit < Software Sources

Once that dialog opens click on the pull down menu that says "Download From" and select other, another dialog will open, click "Select Best Server" your computer will run several tests, and then select the best server based on those test.

- [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

This usually fixes the problem for me.

[image]