# Is es.archive.ubuntu.com down? How can I change it?

Tags: server, archive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

When I try to update with `apt-get update`, it seems to not resolve the server *es.archive.ubuntu.com*. Is it down?

I suppose it's a mirror of archive.ubuntu.com. If it is, how could I set my mirror to archive.ubuntu.com?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the mirror in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. For using the default/main one , use this command

```
sudo sed -i 's/es.archive.ubuntu.com/archive.ubuntu.com/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The command will change the mirror to the default one. And yes, the mirror *es.archive.ubuntu.com* seems to be down atm.

Alternatively, you can open the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with the command `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` in a terminal (open it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut) and remove the `es.` part in front pf `es.archive.ubuntu.com` .

Comment: Thankyou! It worked, now it's OK and the main server seems to be faster than the spanish mirror (strange thing)...