# Software update failed

Tags: 12.04, updates

I tried to update my Ubuntu software and Java through update manager. However, after all about few hours, it does not have any progress also.

The errors message shown

> Software updates correct errors, eliminate security vulnerabilities
>   and provide new features.

I did try to update and upgrade it through terminal but this is the error that I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade && update
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libgnome2-0 linux-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae
  linux-image-generic-pae
The following packages will be upgraded:
  accountsservice apparmor apport apport-gtk apport-symptoms apt
  apt-transport-https apt-utils aptdaemon aptdaemon-data base-files bind9-host
  coreutils dnsutils firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
  firefox-locale-en firefox-locale-zh-hant gir1.2-gudev-1.0
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gnome-power-manager
  icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm jockey-common jockey-gtk
  landscape-client-ui-install libaccountsservice0 libapt-inst1.4
  libapt-pkg4.12 libbind9-80 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libdns81
  libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglu1-mesa libgnome2-common
  libgssglue1 libgudev-1.0-0 libisc83 libisccc80 libisccfg82
  libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libldap-2.4-2
  liblwres80 libparted0debian1 libudev0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
  libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common
  libxatracker1 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-randr0
  libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-xv0 libxcb1 linux-libc-dev
  login lsb-base lsb-release multiarch-support nfs-common onboard
  openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib parted passwd
  python-apport python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
  python-aptdaemon.pkcompat python-problem-report rpcbind sessioninstaller
  thunderbird thunderbird-globalmenu thunderbird-gnome-support
  thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us thunderbird-locale-zh-hant
  thunderbird-locale-zh-tw udev unity-greeter update-manager
  update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common wpasupplicant
  x11-utils xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-intel xterm
104 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 25.5 MB/126 MB of archives.
After this operation, 701 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  base-files coreutils login libc6-dev libc-dev-bin libc-bin libc6
  libapt-pkg4.12 apt libapt-inst1.4 libudev0 lsb-base libldap-2.4-2
  libparted0debian1 libxcb1 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa
  libxcb-glx0 libgudev-1.0-0 libxatracker1 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-dri2-0
  libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-xv0 rpcbind
  lsb-release update-manager update-manager-core aptdaemon
  python-aptdaemon.pkcompat python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-aptdaemon
  aptdaemon-data update-notifier update-notifier-common libglu1-mesa
  multiarch-support passwd apt-utils udev accountsservice libaccountsservice0
  apt-transport-https parted python-problem-report python-apport apport
  apport-gtk apport-symptoms gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gnome-power-manager jockey-gtk
  jockey-common landscape-client-ui-install libgnome2-common nfs-common
  onboard unity-greeter wpasupplicant x11-utils xserver-xorg-input-wacom
  xserver-xorg-video-intel xterm sessioninstaller
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main base-files i386 6.5ubuntu6.4
  403  Forbidden
Err http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main coreutils i386 8.13-3ubuntu3.1
  403  Forbidden

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

What should I do next?

Comment: Try it again. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. If it still errors, change the mirror using `software-sources-gtk`.

Comment: May i know how to change the mirror??

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror