# Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkrb5-3_1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3_i386.deb 403 Forbidden

Tags: 12.04, installation, 12.10, upgrade, package-management

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit with kernel 3.2.0-26-generic and GNOME 3.4.1.

when I run the upgrade manager, I get the option for partial upgrade and details show:

```
install (11)
remove (1)
upgrade (744)
```

then, I start the upgrade and get:

```
Could not download the upgrades


The upgrade has aborted. Please check your Internet connection or installation media and try again. All files downloaded so far have been kept.
Where out of 755 files. It does not download 5:

Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libk5crypto3_1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libgssapi-krb5-2_1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkrb5-3_1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkrb5support0_1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/krb5-locales_1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3_all.deb 403  Forbidden
```

This continues for weeks, I have tried it 15 times already.

Comment: Have you tried [changing the download server (mirror)](http://askubuntu.com/a/37825/88802)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems an issue with the Nepal mirror, try changing the download server as described in [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/q/37753/6969)

Note that changing from `np.archive.ubuntu.com` to `ubuntu.ntc.net.np` won't help since these are the same hosts.