# apt-get update will not work on my server

Tags: apt, repository, mirrors

I've just installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 on my spare box, and I'm using a command line interface only to get my feet a little wet. `ping google.com` does work, so I know my connection is up and running. At first, `sudo apt-get update` gave me a 404 error, so I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror/37754#37754) advice and added those lines to my sources.list file. While I no longer get the 404 error, I now get many errors like the following one:

`Err mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 packages

No mirror file '/var/lib/apt/mirrors/mirrors.ubuntu.com_mirrors.txt' found [Mirror:]`

I get this error with `/restricted`, as in above, and also with `/universe` and `/multiverse`.

I also get this error with `precise-updates`, as in above, and also with `precise-backports` and `precise-security`. I suppose this makes sense, since this is everything that was added into `sources.list`, but I have no idea where to go from here since searching yields nothing, or if the problem is on my end or theirs.

Comment: Please, add the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file in your question.

Comment: Do you need any specific part of it? As far as I know, there is no way to email this file to my other computer to paste on here without updating first. I can copy it by hand, but it will take a few minutes.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought that you were using the computer with the problem. I want to know how did you added the lines. Did you c/p at the top of the file without add/modify nothing else?

Comment: I just added them in at the top of the file without changing anything else.

Comment: Ok, that is fine. Also, to solve the `404` error, you should follow the instructions of [this dedicated post](http://askubuntu.com/q/65911/62483). [The mirrors post](http://askubuntu.com/q/37753/62483) are for preference. Remove those lines leaving the file as it was before and tell me what happens when you try to update.

Comment: Well, I don't have a GUI (intentionally), so I can't use that method, and I get lots of 404s for seemingly just about everything (`precise`, `precise-security`, `precise-updates`), so I'm not really sure what to comment out, if anything.  I also can't download his script with `wget` for some reason (it says the certificate name does not match the host name).

Comment: I just wanted to add that, while I'm not completely sure this is the problem, I believe what was causing it is the fact that I am in a student dormitory right now and the ISP here prevents Internet use until you log in through their website (after which you need to restart your computer), which is, as far as I know, impossible from a CLI. I was able to leave the dorm and successfully connect and install the server. I ended up using Ubuntu Desktop, though, which I'm not sure makes a difference.