# How to add a server to update servers in ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, updates

my update server was configured to "ir.archive.ubuntu.com" and  I downloaded ubuntu updates from it. now that server has been deleted from my update servers list! I don't know how. Is it possible to add this server again to my update server list?

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/a/37825/20054.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you can update the sources.list file with the URL of your update sever as below**

Open Terminal

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Hash all lines and then input the update sever URL as below

```
dep http://www.ir.archive.ubuntu.com
```