# Trouble updating/installing

Tags: installation, updates

Every time I try to update or install something, I get this:

Could not connect to mirror01.th.ifl.net:80

can somebody please explain this? It's really riling me

Comment: Have you tried selecting another mirror to download from? http://askubuntu.com/a/37825/88802

Comment: yeah possibly. Are you a top user on here might I ask?

Comment: I just pressed the "vote to close" button because you appear to have the same question or at least a question applying to the solutions provided in there. That generates an automatic comment that will be removed if others agree to it and then it will get a banner redirecting other users bumping into this question. Feel free to invest some time in this site and you'll gain more reputation (and learn a lot too!). Good luck!

Comment: oh okay thank you. But I just want to know how I should go about learning more about Ubuntu and how to ask questions on here and things like that? You have any idea how I could?