# amazon ec2 ubuntu apt repos outage?

Tags: apt, amazon-ec2

Is there something happened on [Ubuntu Mirror Repos hosted on Amazon S3 Archive](http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/)?

I got the message "forbidden 403" returned from Ubuntu S3 archive

It used to work before, but it stopped working anymore recently. Please advise

```
$ apt-get -y install ruby1.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
puppet-common : Depends: libxmlrpc-ruby
Depends: libopenssl-ruby
Depends: libshadow-ruby1.8 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libaugeas-ruby1.8 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: facter (>= 1.5) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: facter (< 2.0) but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: debconf-utils but it is not going to be installed
ruby1.8 : Depends: libruby1.8 (= 1.8.7.352-2ubuntu1.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/ precise/main augeas-lenses all 0.10.0-0ubuntu4
403 Forbidden
.............
............
```

Comment: You should contact Amazon support, or change the repositories to the official ones.

Comment: See the notes from [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/125252/147044).

Answer (score 3):

Amazon repositories are only available to Amazon registered systems. You can't use them if you are not using Amazon EC2 services (one of their farms), so it denies access to anything that tries to use them.

Change your repositories to the official `http://archive.ubuntu.com/` and you will be fine:

```
sudo sed -i 's/\.s3\.amazonaws\.com//ig' /etc/apt/sources.list{,d/*.list}
sudo apt-get update
```

That should remove Amazon's servers from your list.

Comment: Uh. I have used them in the past... http://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror/125252#125252

Comment: @jrg those ends in `archive.ubuntu.com` while the ones OP has problem with are `archive.ubuntu.com.s3.amazonaws.com`. They are different domains.

Comment: Isn't this what you guys are debating? http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/#outside. Seems pretty clear that Braiam's right!