# Is it better to use the UK or USA server?

Tags: updates, settings, software-sources, webserver

I live in the UK, so it should be better to use the UK ones. But, the USA one is more likely to be well maintained and have the better connection speed.

Which should I use - is there a testing tool, either built in or installable?

I, personally, would prefer a GUI method over command line.

Comment: Why would the USA one be more likely to be well maintained? Canonical is an UK company, after all. O.o

Comment: Now its a dupe of http://askubuntu.com/q/37753/158442 which has the GUI method as the second answer.

Comment: @muru yep it is :) voted too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built in utility in Ubuntu to find the best server.

Click on the drop down to change the server.

[image]

Scroll up to the top and select the top one (mirrors.ubuntu.com). Then click Select Best Server.

[image]

Wait for the tests to finish (about 45 seconds).

[image]

It will select the best one for you. Click Chose Server.

[image]

Enter your password. It will have changed.

[image]

Comment: didn't you see this type of answer before on AU?

Comment: nope, I evidently didn't search the right things.

Comment: @AvinashRaj it's not easy to search for the right things, as Tim showed me a few days ago.