# upgrading missing packages?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

When I try to upgrage packages using `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get the following output

```
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libcompizconfig0 amd64 1:0.9.11.1+14.04.20140701-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main compiz-gnome amd64 1:0.9.11.1+14.04.20140701-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main compiz-plugins-default amd64 1:0.9.11.1+14.04.20140701-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libdecoration0 amd64 1:0.9.11.1+14.04.20140701-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main compiz-core amd64 1:0.9.11.1+14.04.20140701-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main compiz all 1:0.9.11.1+14.04.20140701-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/libcompizconfig0_0.9.11.1+14.04.20140701-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/compiz-gnome_0.9.11.1+14.04.20140701-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/compiz-plugins-default_0.9.11.1+14.04.20140701-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/libdecoration0_0.9.11.1+14.04.20140701-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/compiz-core_0.9.11.1+14.04.20140701-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/compiz/compiz_0.9.11.1+14.04.20140701-0ubuntu1_all.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

and when I manualy went to these links I found out that these repositories are not to be found. I was wondering why am I getting these errors, is there anything that I am missing.

Comment: It likely has nothing to do with you, just try using [another mirror](http://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, index updates in the mirror have replaced those files with newer versions before your local indexes have been updated, so the ones referred to by your out-of-date indexes no longer exist, hence a 404. In this case simply `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` again and you'll be fine.

If pain persists however, then consider switching to another mirror.

Comment: Switching to another mirror solved the problem...
thank you @Jeff