# VLC instalation problem (Installing through Terminal)

Tags: command-line, dependencies, vlc

I wanted to install VLC on Ubuntu, it wasn't working, updated system, than upgraded it, but still it isn't working.

I used both the Ubuntu Software center and the Terminal for that.

In the terminal I typed the command `sudo apt-get install vlc`

The error message terminal gives me is as follows.

```
arif@arifpc:~$ sudo apt-get install vlc
[sudo] password for arif: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.0~rc1-1ppa2~trusty) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libavcodec56 (>= 7:2.4~) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not installable or
                libgles1 but it is not installable
       Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not installable
       Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not installable
       Depends: libva-drm1 but it is not installable
       Depends: libva-x11-1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not installable
       Depends: libva1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not installable
       Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0~pre1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not installable
       Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not installable
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.0~rc1-1ppa2~trusty) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.0~rc1-1ppa2~trusty) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Note:I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I solved this problem the same day, the problem was with the nearest archive.ubuntu.com (Ubuntu Archive Server) I changed all of its instances (13 occurrences in my case) to us.archive.ubuntu.com and it worked.
The configuration file where I changed this setting was /etc/apt/sources.list.

**Edit**: Recently I found another question on askubuntu, the accepted answer to this question is also a nice solution to this problem if you don't want to change the archive.ubuntu address. 
[**Here is that question.**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me after the upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10.

I found this [Solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2250015) that helped me.

You need to add the [xorg-edgers fresh X crack](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) Repository
with this Code in Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa
```

Then Reboot your PC.
Then update the repositories with the following commands and install VLC:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: Or, just the opposite worked for me: `sudo apt install ppa-purge`, `sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers`.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands

`sudo apt-get -f install`

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

This should install all missing dependencies and configure dpkg.

Comment: Thank You Bro, but actually the nearest archieve.ubuntu.com wasn't working, so when i changed it (inside /etc/apt/sources.list) to us.archieve.ubuntu.com, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

By using `aptitude` i can solve this issue.

[source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2367538)

[my topic in UBUNTU.ir community](https://forum.ubuntu.ir/index.php?topic=148832.msg1160733#msg1160733)

***Solution***

`sudo apt install aptitude`

`sudo aptitude install vlc`

> now you must choose: n

Then terminal will output

```
Downgrade the following packages:                                          
1)     libgl1-mesa-glx [12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (now) -> 11.2.0-1ubuntu2 (xenial
2)     libglapi-mesa [12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (now) -> 11.2.0-1ubuntu2 (xenial)]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
```

Now aptitude downgrades depending packages and install vlc.