# Unable to install vlc media player in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, 16.04, dependencies, vlc

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.2+git20160830+r58831+56~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libavcodec-ffmpeg56 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not going to be installed or
            libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libavutil-ffmpeg54 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
            libgles1
   Depends: libgles2-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
            libgles2
   Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libva-drm1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libva-x11-1 (>= 1.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libva1 (>= 1.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not going to be installed
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.2+git20160830+r58831+56~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.2+git20160830+r58831+56~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
   Conflicts: vlc:i386 but 2.1.4-1 is to be installed
vlc:i386 : Depends: vlc-nox:i386 (= 2.1.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libaa1:i386 (>= 1.4p5) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libcaca0:i386 (>= 0.99.beta17-1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libfribidi0:i386 (>= 0.19.2) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                 libgl1:i386
        Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libsdl-image1.2:i386 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libsdl1.2debian:i386 (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libtar0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libva-x11-1:i386 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libva1:i386 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libvlccore7:i386 (>= 2.1.0) but it is not installable
        Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libxcb-composite0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libxcb-keysyms1:i386 (>= 0.3.9) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libxcb-randr0:i386 (>= 1.1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libxcb-shm0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libxcb-xv0:i386 (>= 1.2) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libxcb1:i386 (>= 1.6) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libxpm4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify:i386 (= 2.1.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse:i386 (= 2.1.4-1) but it is not installable
        Conflicts: vlc but 2.2.2+git20160830+r58831+56~ubuntu16.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried eveything `-f` `-f install`

But nothing seems to work.
this is not all when ever i try `sudo apt upgrade`

I get the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc:i386 : Depends: vlc-nox:i386 (= 2.1.4-1) but it is not installed
            Depends: libaa1:i386 (>= 1.4p5) but it is not installed
            Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not installed
            Depends: libcaca0:i386 (>= 0.99.beta17-1) but it is not installed
            Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not installed
            Depends: libfribidi0:i386 (>= 0.19.2) but it is not installed
            Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed
            Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not installed or
                     libgl1:i386
            Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
            Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
            Depends: libsdl-image1.2:i386 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not installed
            Depends: libsdl1.2debian:i386 (>= 1.2.11) but it is not installed
            Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.6) but it is not installed
            Depends: libtar0:i386 but it is not installed
            Depends: libva-x11-1:i386 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not installed
            Depends: libva1:i386 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not installed
            Depends: libvlccore7:i386 (>= 2.1.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not installed
            Depends: libxcb-composite0:i386 but it is not installed
            Depends: libxcb-keysyms1:i386 (>= 0.3.9) but it is not installed
            Depends: libxcb-randr0:i386 (>= 1.1) but it is not installed
            Depends: libxcb-shm0:i386 but it is not installed
            Depends: libxcb-xv0:i386 (>= 1.2) but it is not installed
            Depends: libxcb1:i386 (>= 1.6) but it is not installed
            Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not installed
            Depends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not installed
            Depends: libxpm4:i386 but it is not installed
            Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but it is not installed
            Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify:i386 (= 2.1.4-1) but it is not installed
            Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse:i386 (= 2.1.4-1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I have tried even the `-f` but nothing happens still.

Please Help

Comment: You have tried `-f` as in  `sudo apt-get -f install`?  Because, it's not totally clear from the description you wrote.  It's most likely a typo, but I still prefer to ask.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same issue, and managed to solve with `sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers`. I believe this is a specific version of the duplicated question.

Comment: That `2.2.2+git20160830+r58831+56~ubuntu16.04.1` means you're using a git (testing) version of VLC instead of your distro's default VLC version. Hence, the first step is to remove such repository by running a shell terminal command such as `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/videolan*` (assuming that such repository is owned by Videolan). Afterwards, run the command `sudo apt-get purge vlc -y; sudo apt-get autoremove -y; sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get check; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y; sudo apt-get install vlc -y` in order to install your distro's default (stable) VLC.

Answer (score 22):

The Only Solution to this problem is adding padoka mesa stable repository..

https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa

Then run

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

It will Work Surely As the above repository have both libgles1-mesa and libgles2-mesa required for vlc..

Comment: This sure a life saver. I was doing some stuff recently and I needed to use VLC to find out that something else had uninstalled it, and couldn't install again because of `libgles1-mesa` issues. This such an issue with Debian systems, too many different repos with too many different versions, it's a complete scattering mess when it comes to Debian packages because it likes to break itself.

Comment: seems to fix the general problem of libgles1-mesa nd libgles2-mesa mutual-exclusivity in 16.04.

Comment: Worked perfectly !

Comment: Perfect! Solution still works on 16.04.

Comment: I added this ppa. Then run the command to install vlc and it is still the same error with dependencies :(

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove vlc*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: This works - by removing all versions using the (*) then running the commands one by one finally reinstalling again worked for me.

Comment: I did exactly as recommended here. Spent a lot (!!) of time and it didn't work (the same error with dependencies appear) :(

Comment: after trying almost everything this is the only solution that worked for me.. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can try following the same using the below command

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install vlc
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem of libraries  (cannot install vlc due to issues with libgles1-mesa and libgles2-mesa library dependencies). I could solve the issue using aptitude.

However I could not install vlc right away due to the library dependency issues.

First I had to update libgles1-mesa with
    $ sudo aptitude install libgles1-mesa

to the question to the proposed solution (keeping non-installed library) answer: NO

then accept the alternative proposal: reverting  libgl1-mesa-glx and  libglapi-mesa to previous versions

then I went on with libgles2-mesa with:
    $ sudo aptitude install libgles2-mesa

this time the proposed solution had no issue and installed the library

At this point, I could install vlc with
    $ sudo apt-get install vlc

and vlc was up and operating
Hove it works as well for you!

Comment: This solution would demand, in my case, removing Skype and Wine. This is not a solution.

Comment: Same as previous. Seems that the broken dependencies have to do something with xorg-edgers ppa that I'm using. I'll try to remove the ppa.

Comment: I've ran `ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`, it downgraded a bunch of packages then I was able to install vlc :). Will see if the X still works after a reboot 

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/551301/vlc-instalation-problem-installing-through-terminal

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Directly install it from "Software Center " . Go to Ubuntu software and type in the search box type "VLC". There you can find the player and you can install it by clicking on <kbd>Install</kbd>.
2. Try the following commands in terminal step by step:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install vlc

   sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc (embedded in Mozilla Firefox)
   ```

Comment: I tried the software center thing and the install never completes it gets stuck in the starting only.

Comment: i tried it and nothing is happening eveny with the above terminal commands that u mentioned

Comment: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html

Comment: Download from link and then dpkg  it

Comment: what is dpkg . i am new to ubuntu

Comment: sudo dpkg -i PACKAGENAME

Comment: Here you go detailed explanation about dpkg: https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line/170557

Comment: its not even downloading

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=vlc       download as per your requirement

Comment: This is a major failure of your software management system. Please check for broken packages with synaptic, check the file permissions and correctness of the file '/etc/apt/sources.list' and reload the software information with: 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get install -f'.

Comment: which version of ubuntu are you using ?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: I have added new answer

Answer (score 0):

Add the PPA for daily *pre-release* builds of VLC and install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vlc
```

Now open VLC from the Unity Dash (or equivalent app launcher).

Comment: nope still the dependencis coming in

Comment: are u root user ?

Comment: yes i  am the administrator

Comment: try to restart the pc and try again :  sudo apt update &&
sudo apt install vlc

Comment: i tried it but againa the same error

Answer (score -1):

The following commands worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install -f
```

and then try installing VLC using:

```
sudo apt install vlc
```

Answer (score -1):

After a lot of frustration with unmet dependencies, [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/install-vlc-3-0-2-ubuntu-16-04-ppa/) worked:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vlc-3
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-4
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/meson
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: Downvoted with no explanation.