# Upgrading LTS server using do-release-upgrade fails (could not download all upgrades)

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, server, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I've been trying to upgrade two servers from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS for a few days now using `do-release-upgrade`. It seems that they're both getting hung up on downloading the last of two updates.

For one, I can't fetch *vim-runtime* from trusty/main and *linux-headers-3.13.0-45* from trusty-updates/main.
For the other, I again can't fetch *vim-runtime* from and *libicu-dev*.

In all cases, I get some variation of

`Err http://xx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ <blah blah>
    Connection failed [IP: nnn.nn.nn.nn 80]`

where the country prefix, package, and IP address are different depending on the download that's failing.

I've tried changing `/etc/apt/sources.list` to various mirrors (Canada, US, Germany, and without a country prefix) and running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` after each change to the sources list.

I've even tried adding Amazon's EC2 mirros [per this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror) and I still get the same connection failures.

I can ping the IP addresses. I can even `wget` the .deb packages directly from the failed-to-fetch links provided when `do-release-upgrade` aborts.

Both servers are running as virtual machines under Hyper-V on the same Windows server. All other updates downloaded (eventually).

Any thoughts on how I can move past this issue and upgrade these servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I was never able to resolve the issue of *why* the downloads for these packages would not complete, I was finally able to complete the upgrade as follows:

1. `cd /var/cache/apt/archives`
2. `wget package_name.deb`
3. Repeat step 2 for all missing packages.
4. `do-release-upgrade`

Hope this helps anyone else that might be having difficulty with this.