# Slow Repositories

Tags: apt, software-center, repository, official-repositories

I have the following problem with my two Ubuntu installations at home: installing software using apt-get or the software center takes AGES, I mean, the download speed is very slow. I have already tried to change the server and other tips found on the web at no avail.

Firstly I thought that was a problem with my ISP, but then I downloaded the DEB files for skype and chrome and both got downloaded at regular speed (340 KBps, I have a 3 mbps connection). All internet pages and services work correctly.

Also, when I was installing ubuntu, I ticked the option to install updates and 3rd party software, what a mistake, it took more than 4 hours for the installation to complete because I had to skip the installation of those files (the installer indicated that 105 minutes were remaining for the installation).

A simple sudo apt-get update takes 20 minutes and the installation of scribus (20 mb download) took 26.
As I said before, I have already tried changing server, but the problem still persists in my two computers.
Any Idea?

BTW, one computer uses ubuntu 15.04 32 bits and the other 64 bits.
Thank you

Comment: By saying, that you've changed the server, what kind of servers did you try? When choosing a country based server, you can actually hit several instances as several servers in that country offer repositories.

Comment: Hi, I tried Ubuntu's main server, my country's server, and like 4 or 5 of the list. All of them work very slow. <35 kbps. Apt-fast works good, but is just a temporary solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run the following commands to install apt-fast which uses aria2 as a download manager:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/myppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-fast
```

then, instead of using apt-get in the future, use:

```
sudo apt-fast
```

instead.

example:

```
sudo apt-fast upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-fast install packagename
```

more info: [github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast](https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast)

see also: [how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

Comment: It worked great. But I'm still wondering why apt-get is so slow. Thank you!

Comment: Some servers are just not very fast. It is recommended you take advantage of multiple mirrors. You can search for the fastest mirror using the software center or you can check out this answer also http://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror