# How to update Flash? (version numbers don't match)

Tags: updates, software-center, flash

**Edit:** There actually seems to be an issue with Flash not correctly downloading and updating through *flashplugin-installer*. Don't ignore it! Check [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/647063).

---

I'm apologize if the answer is extremely straightforward, but my flash needs updating, and I'm unsure how to do that.

I installed Flash initially through the Software Center because if I download an executable file from, say, the Adobe website, I'm at a dead end.  It doesn't start the install automatically through some gui interface, and I don't know the command line to install it.  So, that's my problem now - I'm at a dead end if I just download the new version of Flash and update through the Adobe site, but I don't see anything in the Software Center that says "get updates."

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 6):

## Edit: Flash version numbers don't match

I just noticed that the plugin page in Firefox told me that the version I had installed was vulnerable though I had the latest version of the of `flashplugin-installer` installed and it matched with the [version number of the plugin for Linux on Adobe's site](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/).

However what I must have ignored: **the version number for Flash in Firefox was lower!**

After running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer` it re-downloaded Adobe Flash and all version numbers matched up *without* restarting Firefox.

---

[image]

You should be able to find an entry in your USC history or the apt log when the package was updated the last time. Just run the `update-manager` from the dash to search for new packages and install them.

Alternatively you could remove the package and reinstall it, here is the corresponding page for the package: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/flashplugin-installer/

It should have been updated a while ago unless there is an issue with the repository that your installation uses. Here is a description to [test and change the repository server](https://askubuntu.com/a/37825/40581).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see if your Flash, or any other program needs updating, is to install **Synaptic Package Manager**.  In the GUI, click on **Mark all upgrades**.  If no updates are marked by **Synaptic** you are up-to-date.

To install **Synaptic**, open Terminal

```
    sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

To run **Synaptic** alt+F2, and enter Synaptic. Click on the icon, and enter your admin password.

To verify your **flash** installation, enter **flash** in the search box at the top right of the **Synaptic** window.