# Ubuntu 15.10 freezes a lot usually while playing any media through web

Tags: freeze

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and am facing system freeze quite frequently while playing any form of media through web (youtube/dailymotion/hotstar etc.).
Each time this happens , I need to restart my machine using the Power ON/OFF Button.
I have tried the solution provided in the link:
[What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)
This doesn't help either.

I have thought about downgrading to ubuntu 15.04 but I have a few applications installed and am lazy enough to install all dependencies again.
Was just hoping if someone might be able to help me out , i won't have to go through all that pain.

Thanks 
Ankur

Comment: Which graphics adapter and driver are you running?

Comment: In any case, *upgrading* is almost always better than downgrading.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do, is check if Adobe Flash, is the latest version. Read through this question (and answers) for instructions on how to do that.

[How to update Flash? (version numbers don't match)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646996/how-to-update-flash-version-numbers-dont-match)

Comment: Flash was up-to-date. However, I uninstalled chrome and chromium along with their flash plugins to see if that might be the issue. But alas , that dindn't work too.  Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: OK one more thing to try - install Ubuntu restricted extras, to make sure you have all the codecs. http://askubuntu.com/questions/56446/how-do-i-install-the-ubuntu-restricted-extras-package

Comment: Ubuntu Restricted extras is up-to-date. I think I may have to reinstall ubuntu. :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some days ago. Brand new desktop-pc running 15.10.

It freezes while playing media from YouTube and other web-sources, so first I blamed flash too. Strange to me was that on an old sub-notebook running exactly the same software, the errors do not occur. Further checks revealed that it crashes as well if the videos are HTML5. I suggest you to check this too.

In my case the problem was more a driver issue, similar to the stuff described here [Bug-Report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88012) 
Since I found no correct Release I added another graphic card and now all is running fine.

I hope this gives you a clue. The nasty part with the error in this area is that different problems seem to have similar symptoms. Good luck.

Comment: Good to hear that you found a solution!! I am considering of reinstalling ubuntu. Just don't want to download and install all the python packages again. That is such a pain