# Cannot Update ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: 14.04, server, updates

I am using ubuntu server version 14.04 and i need to update some of the packages but problem comes when i enter a command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It update some packages but it get stuck at one point which is:

```
0%(connection to archive.ubuntu.com)
```

Please tell me how to tackle this problem..

Comment: change the server to the closest one to you.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly archive.ubuntu.org is slow, or just slow from where you are. Read this:

[How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)