# Can't install VLC

Tags: vlc

I'm trying to install VLC on Ubuntu by using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

After trying to run the first command, an error is thrown:

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

After running the second second command it gives another error:

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What to do?

Comment: Use another mirror and enable universe. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu and http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/vlc

Comment: i have taken screenshot but dont know how to paste it here.Is it possible to paste that here?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping.My problem is solved.In /etc/apt/sources.list i double click the  sources.list file and change the  server location to main server.Thats it.Now every command is running like Sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get upgrade sudo apt-get install vlc.Thanks everyone once again.