# add text to read only file

Tags: repository, software-sources

as written [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror),
I should put this lines:

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

on the top in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and this should be all that is needed to make it automatically pick a mirror for me based on my geographical location.

because the file ***sources.list*** is read-only, what should I do?

tried
`$ sudo mount -o rw,remount /etc/apt/sources.list`
but it wasn't found..

Comment: You need to edit the file as root. `sudo -e /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's check the default permission of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 2563 Aug 21 04:24 /etc/apt/sources.list
```

As you can see only user `root` and the members of group `root` can write to the file, all other users while trying to edit the file will get a message saying that the file is read only for them.

To edit the file, just use `sudo` to impersonate `root` e.g. using `nano` :

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or `gedit`:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Do you really think that OP will be able to use vim?

Comment: @Pilot6 That goes as an example as you can see i.e. i am not telling OP to use `vim`, its merely an example..on a different note how come you are confident about what they are comfortable with ?

Comment: I know. But OP does not know anything about permissions or sudo. So this is not a good example. Even nano will cause problems how to paste there.

Comment: actually I do understand the `sudo` command, I know it is like "open as manager" in windows..
I did it and opened it with `gedit`, added the code and it worked. thanks!

Comment: @TzahiLeh Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have yo edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` manually.

You can go to System Settings -> Software & Updates and setup your mirror there in GUI. It is "Download from" drop down menu.