# How do I switch to a closer Ubuntu mirror?

Tags: 14.04, apt, repository, software-sources

After I have performed one of `sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt g++` procedure I found that Ubuntu is planning to download more than 400Mb and it will take more than 2 hours. It is too long. I also found that it downloads from the US:

```
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libservlet3.0-java 
all 7.0.52-1ubuntu0.3 [294 kB]
```

I'm in Europe, maybe should I somehow tell Ubuntu to download from a source located closer. How should I do that?

Comment: Related but very old 2011 http://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror

Comment: Visit [Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Download_Server)

Answer (score 8):

Go to software & updates app in dash and on the first page it says `Download from:` set the server here

[image]

Set your nearest server, of course, in the dropdown.

Answer (score 7):

edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to contain the url of [your closest mirror](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors).

e.g.

```
deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe
```

or whichever mirror you choose. change all the occurrences of `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/` to the URL of the mirror of your choice.

Answer (score 5):

Go to **Software & Updates** → **Ubuntu Software** tab → **Download from** → **Other...** → **Select Best Server**

[image: screenshot of "Software & Updates"]

[image: screenshot of "Choose a Download Server"]