# What should I do when apt tries to fetch a package that doesn't exist?

Tags: apt

I am trying to install the `checkinstall` package with:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

`apt-get` is returning

```
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-67.88_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 198.199.99.226 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I've checked at the [ubuntu package servers](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/) and that specific package: `linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-67.88_amd64.deb` in not present on the server although there are many packages with similar version numbers, this one looks closest: `linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-72.93_i386.deb`

What should I do from here to fix this problem and finish installing `checkinstall`?

Comment: I checked the ubuntu package server that you linked to and the file you referenced [is definitely there](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-72.93_i386.deb). To fix the error you're seeing, try running `sudo apt-get install -f`. That should attempt to fix whatever is missing. If you still can't pull a file down, your issue might be with your repo. You might need to [change repositories](http://askubuntu.com/a/682576/606758). I've had similar issues with the neusoft repo in China. The file in question shouldn't be related to repo though.

Comment: Or run `apt-get update` again to refresh the package lists.

Comment: @b_laoshi the package you linked to was the wrong one, if you re-read the question you should understand.

Comment: @muru  `apt-get update` can't help `apt`, when the package doesnt exist on the server, right?

Comment: @the_velour_fog, sorry for reading that wrong. Like muru says, run `sudo apt-get update` if you haven't done that already. Then try running sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev. If that fails, try a manual install. Download the more recent version run `sudo dpkg -i linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-72.93_i386.deb` That should install the most recent version which is the one you noted that looks closest. If this install goes through, run sudo apt-get install -f. Assuming linux-libc-dev was your only dependency problem, that last command should reattempt the installation of checkinstall and finish it off.

Comment: @b_laoshi, thanks, yes I have done as you have said, basically - the packages installed, so I have  added the result as an answer, although I'm worried Ive now broken my OS. can you please explain what `apt-get -f` would do? (I'm assuming you meant `apt-get install -f checkinstall` right?)

Comment: It's just shorthand for `apt-get install --fix-missing`. When you try to install something and install fails because dependencies aren't met, running `apt-get install -f` should attempt to pick up where it left off with the installs that failed. You can add checkinstall to the end if you like, but it's not necessary. That's my experience, anyway. Regarding muru's recommendation to run `apt-get update` that's good practice to make sure it's not trying to pull an obsolete package. I should have told you to run that first as well.

Comment: @b_laoshi I dont understand *pick up where it left off?* how can `--fix-missing` fix the problem - if the dependencies still are unavailable? I ran `apt-get update` - it made no difference

Comment: @the_velour_fog, basically, apt-get knows it was unable to complete the installation. If you can fix the missing/broken dependencies manually, it will retry the installation when you run install with --fix-missing. Essentially, you fixed what was missing. Now when apt-get tries again, it thinks the problem is resolved and finishes off installing anything that didn't get installed on the first attempt. If your system is trying to pull an older version of a current package, I would suspect that you might need to clear out cache somewhere and run apt-get update anew.

Comment: @b_laoshi ah so `--fix-missing` is what you use after **I fixed the dependency** - I thought it was a command telling  `apt` to fix it. but its like saying *ok, apt, now that Ive manually "fixed the missing dependencies", now you can re-try installing the package that failed* .. thats it right?

Comment: @the_velour_fog, precisely. In hindsight, maybe we should have taken this  discussion to chat.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may be interested, I came up with a solution, although I dont think it was a good solution.
Essentially, I *hoped* the package which was requiring `linux-libc-dev` would hopefully accept a range of `linux-libc-dev` versions.
So I curled the closest version into `/var/cache/apt/archives`

```
% cd /var/cache/apt/archives
%
..cache/apt/archives % sudo curl -O 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-72.93_amd64.deb'
%
cache/apt/archives % sudo dpkg --install linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-72.93_amd64.deb
%
```

The `linux-libc-dev` and `checkinstall` packages have now installed, but it looks like it may have displaced many other packages

```
cache/apt/archives % sudo dpkg --install linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-72.93_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package linux-libc-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 60543 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-72.93_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.4.0-72.93) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.4.0-72.93) ...
%
cache/apt/archives % sudo apt-get install checkinstall  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  build-essential cpp cpp-5 dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-5 gcc gcc-5 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan2 libatomic1
  libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libdpkg-perl libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcc-5-dev libgomp1 libisl15 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpx0
  libquadmath0 libstdc++-5-dev libtsan0 libubsan0 make manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  gettext cpp-doc gcc-5-locales debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-5-multilib gcc-5-doc libstdc++6-5-dbg gcc-multilib autoconf automake libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc
  gcc-5-multilib libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan2-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libubsan0-dbg libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx0-dbg libquadmath0-dbg
  glibc-doc libstdc++-5-doc make-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential checkinstall cpp cpp-5 dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-5 gcc gcc-5 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan2
  libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libdpkg-perl libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcc-5-dev libgomp1 libisl15 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3
  libmpx0 libquadmath0 libstdc++-5-dev libtsan0 libubsan0 make manpages-dev
0 upgraded, 35 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/35.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 126 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Selecting previously unselected package libmpc3:amd64.
(Reading database ... 61354 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libmpc3_1.0.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmpc3:amd64 (1.0.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libc-dev-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../libc-dev-bin_2.23-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc-dev-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libc6-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev_2.23-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libisl15:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libisl15_0.16.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libisl15:amd64 (0.16.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cpp-5.
Preparing to unpack .../cpp-5_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cpp-5 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cpp.
Preparing to unpack .../cpp_4%3a5.3.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cpp (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcc1-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libcc1-0_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcc1-0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgomp1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libgomp1_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgomp1:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libitm1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libitm1_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libitm1:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libatomic1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libatomic1_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libatomic1:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libasan2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libasan2_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libasan2:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblsan0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../liblsan0_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblsan0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtsan0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libtsan0_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtsan0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libubsan0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libubsan0_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libubsan0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcilkrts5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libcilkrts5_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcilkrts5:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmpx0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libmpx0_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmpx0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libquadmath0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libquadmath0_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libquadmath0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgcc-5-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libgcc-5-dev_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgcc-5-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gcc-5.
Preparing to unpack .../gcc-5_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-5 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gcc.
Preparing to unpack .../gcc_4%3a5.3.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libstdc++-5-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libstdc++-5-dev_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++-5-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package g++-5.
Preparing to unpack .../g++-5_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking g++-5 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package g++.
Preparing to unpack .../g++_4%3a5.3.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking g++ (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package make.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/make_4.1-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking make (4.1-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdpkg-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libdpkg-perl_1.18.4ubuntu1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libdpkg-perl (1.18.4ubuntu1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dpkg-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../dpkg-dev_1.18.4ubuntu1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking dpkg-dev (1.18.4ubuntu1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package build-essential.
Preparing to unpack .../build-essential_12.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking build-essential (12.1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package checkinstall.
Preparing to unpack .../checkinstall_1.6.2-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking checkinstall (1.6.2-4ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfakeroot:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libfakeroot_1.20.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfakeroot:amd64 (1.20.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
Preparing to unpack .../fakeroot_1.20.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fakeroot (1.20.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libalgorithm-diff-perl_1.19.03-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.19.03-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl_0.04-4build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-4build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-merge-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libalgorithm-merge-perl_0.08-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfile-fcntllock-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libfile-fcntllock-perl_0.22-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfile-fcntllock-perl (0.22-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package manpages-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../manpages-dev_4.04-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking manpages-dev (4.04-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Setting up libmpc3:amd64 (1.0.3-1) ...
Setting up libc-dev-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Setting up libc6-dev:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Setting up libisl15:amd64 (0.16.1-1) ...
Setting up cpp-5 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Setting up cpp (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libcc1-0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Setting up libgomp1:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Setting up libitm1:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Setting up libatomic1:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Setting up libasan2:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Setting up liblsan0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Setting up libtsan0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Setting up libubsan0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Setting up libcilkrts5:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Setting up libmpx0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Setting up libquadmath0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Setting up libgcc-5-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Setting up gcc-5 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Setting up gcc (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libstdc++-5-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Setting up g++-5 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ...
Setting up g++ (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/g++ to provide /usr/bin/c++ (c++) in auto mode
Setting up make (4.1-6) ...
Setting up libdpkg-perl (1.18.4ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up dpkg-dev (1.18.4ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up build-essential (12.1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up checkinstall (1.6.2-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libfakeroot:amd64 (1.20.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up fakeroot (1.20.2-1ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (fakeroot) in auto mode
Setting up libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.19.03-1) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-4build1) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-3) ...
Setting up libfile-fcntllock-perl (0.22-3) ...
Setting up manpages-dev (4.04-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
```

Comment: It doesn't look like anything was displaced. They are probably other checkinstall dependencies. After you manually installed linux-libc-dev it enabled you to finish installing checkinstall and all of its associated dependencies.

Comment: @b_laoshi ah ok good point about the dependencies belonging to `checkinstall`