# How to install "libboost-all-dev" on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 trough apt-get

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, dependencies, boost

I am making a mangos WoW auto-configuration personal script and I need libboost to compile the application as it is now a requirement.
My distro is:

```
mangos@mangos-VB:~/Documents/setup/UbuntuBatches/MaNGOS$ uname -a
Linux mangos-VB 4.4.0-66-lowlatency #87-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 3 `16:43:09 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
```

I have the following output when tried to install it:

```
mangos@mangos-VB:~/Documents/setup/UbuntuBatches/MaNGOS$ sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-all-dev : Depends: libboost-date-time-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-filesystem-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-iostreams-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-log-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-python-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-regex-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-system-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-thread-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-wave-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
mangos@mangos-VB:~/Documents/setup/UbuntuBatches/MaNGOS$

mangos@mangos-VB:~/Documents/setup/UbuntuBatches/MaNGOS$ sudo apt-cache policy libboost-all-dev

libboost-all-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.58.0.1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.58.0.1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Hi, in my case "aptitude" wants to remove the "ubuntu-core-launcher"

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output of `apt-cache policy libboost-all-dev`. And by the way, your kernel is out of date; the latest version is 4.4.0-72. Make sure you have the `linux-lowlatency` metapackage installed.

Comment: `linux-lowlatency is already the newest version (4.4.0.66.70).`

Comment: [The latest version is normally 4.4.0.72.78.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/linux-lowlatency) Have you run `sudo apt update` recently?

Comment: Yes, it finished in seconds just now

Comment: Maybe your mirror is out of date then, try [using another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/682532/ubuntu-repository-change).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56863/discussion-between---and-fkraiem).

Comment: I currently got `"Main server", "Server for United states", "Server for Bulgaria"`

This seems pretty obvious for me because it wants to download from a mirror which is closer,  though I will suggest that the main server should be the default one to avoid such problems in the future.

As it seems to download slower than before, It did not gave me this same error and started the update process. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like `@fkraiem` said, my `apt-get` list was outdated, and because of that, `apt` could not get the dependencies in question. My update server was set to `Bulgaria`, because it is the closest possible one. The problem got fixed when I went to `Software and updates -> Ubuntu software -> Drop down /Download from:/ -> Select /Main server/`. After that `Close` and `Reload` buttons clicked. Open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and enter `sudo apt-get update`. And voila, It's fixed !