# Failed to fetch, no release file, connection failed errors when running `sudo apt-get update`

Tags: server, apt, updates

I am new to Ubuntu and SE. I have recently installed Xenial 16.04 to my test server and I have tried to run a apt-get update before trying to install any packages. Unfortunately, it seems to have failed with the following error.

```
Ign:63 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Translation-en
Ign:64 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:65 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried to disable IPv6, run `apt-get autoclean`, `apt-get-clean` and then an update again. Is it normal I still get all the other links showing Ignore in the update process after a clean?

My sources.list file

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)]/ xenial main restricted

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
#deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
#deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

#deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
#deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
#deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb http://ubuntu.ipserverone.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
#deb-src http://ubuntu.ipserverone.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
```

Comment: Use an alternate mirror - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/682532/ubuntu-repository-change

Comment: Tried adding a nearer mirror shows the same result.

Comment: You posted the same repository. Use an alternate mirror. If you do not need the source packages disable them (deb-src) , just a general comment. If you have this problem with multiple mirrors you will have to wait or file a bug report as there is no way for you to fix this.

Comment: It looks like you're using "my.archive.ubuntu.com" instead of "us.archive.ubuntu.com" like the other repositories that are commented out in your sources.list. Is that on purpose? If so, is it the second mirror you tried?

Comment: I have modified all into "my.archive.ubuntu.com" since it is closer to my location. It seems that the environment I am hosted on is blocked with a firewall it seems as I was able to run it once I host the same machine in my home environment.

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely to be caused by the Firewall implemented in the network layer instead blocking all the APT-GET updates to work. I have moved my machine to an alternate network and the error seems to be resolved.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to fix it! You should accept your answer so people can see that this is something that can be fixed.